# How to find object by its id in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I can't have object by its id in Django Rest Framework. I have a such model:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)    
    content = models.TextField()    
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Then I write a serializer:

```
class BlogPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ('title', 'content', 'created')
```

In my `views.py` I have this:

```
class BlogPostListFilter(dajngo_filter.FilterSet):
     blog_post_id = django_filters.NumerFilter(name = 'id')

     class Meta:
          model = BlogPost
          fiields = ['blog_post_id']


class BlogPostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
     queryset = BlogPost.objects.all()
     serializer_class = BlogPostSerializer
     permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
     filter_class = BlogPostListFilter
     paginate_by = 100
```

And such code in my urls:

```
url(r'^blogpost/$', ListCreateAPIView.as_view(model=BlogPost), name='blogpost-list'),
```

But when I write in browser http://example.com/blogpost/?blog_post_id=1 I have all objects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to use `ListCreateAPIView`. You need to make some changes:

**urls.py**:

```
url(r'^blogpost/(?P<post_id>\w+)$', views.BlogPostList.as_view(),name='blogpost-list'),
```

**views.py**

```
class BlogPostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
   serializer_class = BlogPostSerializer
   permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
   filter_class = BlogPostListFilter
   paginate_by = 100

   def get_queryset(self):
      queryset = BlogPost.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['post_id'])
      return queryset
```

But I think that Django Rest Framework provides better Class Based Views for your use case, such as `RetrieveAPIView`. As far as I understand, it seems that you just want to get an object, and this generic view is for a list of objects.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I stumbled upon this question looking to access the object id while overriding a ModelViewSet's retrieve method. After some research and experimentation, I discovered that the object id is stored in a dictionary called self.kwargs in the `'pk'` key.

I am using djangorestframework==3.11.0.

```
class MealItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset =MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.MyModelSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # The Primary Key of the object is passed to the retrieve method through self.kwargs
        object_id = self.kwargs['pk']
```

I hope this answer helps another forlorn StackOverflow wanderer at some point!